# Is it possible to supply ip AND hostname in URL?

Tags: url

I'd like to give a URL to some non-tech coworkers so that they can view a proof on a webpage on our test server.

This server is not in their DNS, so I'd like to supply them the IP, but there are *several* sites running on the same IP. Is there a way to put the IP address *and* the hostname into a url? Else, is there another way to achieve my aim (besides asking my coworkers to alter their hosts file)?

Answer (score 3):

Not that I know of. You could maybe host the site on an alternative port though? Then you could just use the ip and the port for the url.

Comment: Good suggestion. Not up to me, though, and I fear the server admin is weary of my requests.

Comment: @JellicleCat Won't hurt to ask, I hope. If it does, maybe your organization has some more issues :p